# Задать несколько условий в оператор elif. TeleBot, PyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем привет. Есть код, но в нем нужно указать несколько условий. Например, если юзер введет и отправит 1 или 2 (или 1 и 2), то программа отправит определенный текст.

Я знаю, что можно решить с помощью еще одного elif, но вдруг есть способ чтобы не писать слишком много кода, а просто задать условия.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def all_mes(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if (здесь нужно как-то вставить несколько условий) in message.text:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Похоже на цифры")
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-logical-operators-with-examples-improvement-needed/

Comment: @Igor Спасибо вам